# gsutil command not found when executing in a seperate step - bitbucket pipelines

Tags: shell, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines, gsutil

```
image: node:14.15.4
pipelines:
branches:
'INSTALL STEP':
  - step:
      name: Install Gcloud and transfer files
      script:
        - echo "starting build"
        - <<I INSTALL GCLOUD HERE FROM A SEPERATE SH FILE, ALSO PATHS ARE SET>>
  - step:
      name: gsutil execution
      script:
        - gsutil cp <<some code goes here>>
```

The issue I am facing is, error coming as gsutil: command not found if I put the gsutil in a seperate step. It works fine if I put it in the script where I install gcloud from. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought the directory that contains the gsutil executable (`<gcloud_sdk_dir>/bin/`) is probably not in the `PATH` being used when your command is run. You could verify this by running `echo $PATH` in both scenarios and comparing them.

But, after looking at the bitbucket docs, it seems you'll need to declare the files produced in one step (e.g. the gcloud files you installed) as "artifacts" in order to use them in subsequent steps.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/

Comment: okay thanks for the answer. One question is, so if I keep the files as artifacts, how do I execute gsutil command in next step ??. It still gives me gsutil command not found.

Comment: Andrew's answer goes into a bit more detail about how to do that, but the general idea is: in subsequent steps, you'll either need to invoke gsutil using its absolute path (rather than just `gsutil`), or export your `PATH` environment variable, such that it includes the directory containing the gsutil executable, before running your other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your second step will fail because:

> Each step in your pipeline runs a separate Docker container. If you want, you can use different types of containers for each step by selecting different images.

If you would like your second step to access `file.txt', for example, you need to define it as an artifact.

```yaml
artifact:
    - files/*.txt
```

To declare `gcloud` it would be something like below. However, there will be other dependencies that you will need to consider including setting the `PATH`.

```yaml
- step:
    name: Install Gcloud and transfer files
    script:
      - echo "starting build"
      - <<I INSTALL GCLOUD HERE FROM A SEPERATE SH FILE, ALSO PATHS ARE SET>>
    artifact:
      - /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/**
       . . .
```

Because each step runs in a Docker container, you can also declare a different container for each step if required. You could use the Google SDK Docker image instead to ensure the dependencies are correct.

```yaml
- step:
    name: Install Gcloud and transfer files
    image: google/cloud-sdk:160.0.0
    script:
      - npm install
      - npm test
      - npm run build
    artifact:
      - files/to/transfer
```

Comment: Hello may I get some answer as well about how to use gcloud cli on BB Pipelines?
Here is the community question link: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Firebase-Test-Lab-using-gcloud-CLI-on-pipelines/qaq-p/1728481

Thank you!